Find area of figure and volume of body
Problem
Find area:
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2=\frac{xy}{c^2},\qquad a,b,c > 0$$
My solution:
The figure encloses area under itself so we're looking at: $$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2\leq\frac{xy}{c^2},\qquad a,b,c > 0$$
The function is symmetric in first and third quadrant, therefore if $S_D$ is the total area under the function defined in domain $D$ and $D1$ is the domain only for $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ (first quadrant): $S_D=2S_{D1}$
$D1$: $$(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2})^2\leq\frac{xy}{c^2} \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge y \geq 0 \wedge a,b,c > 0$$
And by chekcing $(x,y)=(0,0)$
$$0\leq\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2\leq\frac{xy}{c^2} \wedge x \geq 0 \wedge y \geq 0 \wedge a,b,c > 0$$
(But $\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2$ is always positive for every $x$ and $y$)
And from here I don't really know how to continue to get the double integral that calculates the area for the figure. I'm pretty sure I have to express $y$ or $x$ as a function of the other, but I don't know how to form the function which has 4th, 2nd and 1st degree terms.
I also tried polar coordinates change of variables, but to no avail (but I did know it wouldn't work since there's also terms of first degree on the right side of the equation):
$$S_D = 2\int \int_{D1} \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2 - \frac{xy}{c^2}\, dx\, dy$$

You're on the right track thinking of doing this in polar coordinates.  Did you make the change of variables?  Can you show what you got?

@DMcMor Well I just did $x=r\cos{t}$ and $y=r\sin{t}$ for $r>=0$, $t \in [0, 2 \pi)$, but I couldn't express r (assumed t was way harder since it would require arcsin and arcos). And I also thought that polar coordinates was supposed to happen after finding the domain and doing it in the integral itself and doing Jacobian determinant which is equal to "r" for polar change. But thinking about it now I guess there is no problem substituting with polar coordinates before integration, but I still can't think of a way to express r or t from the equation of the domain.

Carry out the substitution and get is as simplified as you can, you won't need to use any inverse trig functions.  Once you have $r = f(\theta)$ you can use $A = \frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta r^2 , d\theta$ for an appropriate choice of the limits of integration to pick up one quadrant of the curve.  You will end up with a integral that can be solved with substitution.

@DMcMor okay I try that, thank you. One of the solutions is 0 and the other is +/- sqrt(...). So the inequality would be true for r in (-sqrt, sqrt). And I just do a single integral with that range?

You will end up with a range for $\theta$ instead of $r$, and that will be easier to find once you have the polar form.

@DMcMor Thanks a lot! And one last question, would the solution be similar for a problem about volume of figure between $z^2=xy$ and $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}$ and in the first quadrant (all x, y, z positive) So almost the same just substitute abc with numbers and to the power of 4 instead of two. Would this require double integration, since it's volume?

Let:
$$D=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2\le\frac{xy}{c^2}
\}$$
$$S_D=\int_D\int dx dy$$
let :$$(x,y)=(ar \cos(\theta),br \sin(\theta))$$
$$D_1=\{(r,\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^{+}×]0,2\pi]:0 \le r\le \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{ab\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)} , 0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2} \}$$
Therfore:
$$S_D=\int_D \int dx dy = \int_{D_{1}}\int abr dr d\theta=ab\int^{\frac{\pi}{2} }_{0}\int^{\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{ab\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}}_{0}r dr d\theta=\left({\frac{ab}{2c}}\right)^2$$
So:
Area is $2S_D=\frac{a^2b^2}{2c^2}$

Thank you very much!

Clearly the curve $C$ defined by the equation consists of two closed curves in quadrants one and three by symmetry. So one can only consider the closed curve in quadrant one. Letting $x=ar\cos\theta, y=br\sin\theta$ in
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2=\frac{xy}{c^2} $$
one has
$$ r=\frac1c\sqrt{ab\sin\theta\cos\theta}, \theta\in[0,\pi/2]. $$
So
$$ x=\frac1ca^{3/2}b^{1/2}\sin^{1/2}\theta\cos^{3/2}\theta,y=\frac1ca^{1/2}b^{3/2}\sin^{3/2}\theta\cos^{1/2}\theta. $$
So
$$ A=\int_Cxdy=\frac2{c^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}a^{3/2}b^{1/2}\sin^{1/2}\theta\cos^{3/2}\theta\cdot a^{1/2}b^{3/2}\frac{(1+2\cos(2\theta))\sin^{1/2}\theta}{2\cos^{1/2}\theta}d\theta=\frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos\theta(1+\cos(2\theta))d\theta=\frac{a^2b^2}{2c^2}. $$

Thank you very much!

Just to add one more solution to the mix:
Consider the curve defined by $$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)^2=\frac{xy}{c^2},\qquad a,b,c > 0$$
Making the substitutions $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{r^2\cos^2(\theta)}{a^2}+\frac{r^2\sin^2(\theta)}{b^2}\right)^2&=\frac{r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{c^2}\\[5pt]
r^4\left(\frac{b^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta)}{a^2b^2}\right)^2&=\frac{r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{c^2}\\[5pt]
r^2 &=\frac{a^4b^4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{c^2(b^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta))^2}
\end{align*}
$$
From this we can see that $r = 0$ at $\theta = 0,\ \frac{\pi}{2}$, etc. so we can find the area in the first quadrant using
$$
\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}r^2\,d\theta\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{a^4b^4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{c^2(b^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta))^2}\,d\theta\\[5pt]
&=\frac{a^4b^4}{2c^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{(b^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta))^2}\,d\theta\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$
Now, make the substitution
$$
\begin{align*}
u &= b^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta) &&u(0) = b^2\\[5pt]
du &= 2(a^2-b^2)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\,d\theta &&u(\pi/2) = a^2
\end{align*}$$
This gives us
$$
\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{a^4b^4}{4c^2(a^2-b^2)}\int_{b^2}^{a^2}\frac{du}{u^2} = \frac{a^4b^4}{4c^2(a^2-b^2)}\frac{1}{u}\Bigg|_{b^2}^{a^2}=\frac{a^4b^4}{4c^2(a^2-b^2)}\left(\frac{1}{b^2} - \frac{1}{a^2}\right)\\[8pt]
&=\frac{a^4b^4}{4c^2(a^2-b^2)}\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2b^2}\right) = \frac{a^2b^2}{4c^2}
\end{align*}
$$
The total area of both pieces of the curve then is $$2A = \frac{a^2b^2}{2c^2}$$

Thank you very much!
